# Join where lambda query in EF Core 3.1

Tags: c#, .net, linq, lambda, entity-framework-core

I have a problem to write in lambda query this sql query:

```
select c.Id, c.Name, c.SomeNumber, count(*) from TableA a
  inner join TableB b
  on a.Id = b.aId
  inner join TableC c
  on c.BId = b.Id
  where b.Status = N'Approved'
  and c.Scope = N'Scope1'
  group by a.Id, a.Name, a.SomeNumber
```

Can you guys help me with this one ? I want to write lambda query to execute this in code. I'm using EF Core 3.1

This is what I ended up so far:

```
var query = await _dbContext.TableA.Where(a => a.TableB.Any(b => b.Status.Equals("Approved")
                && b.TableC.Any(c => c.Scope.Equals("Scope1"))))
                .GroupBy(g => new { Id = g.Id, Name = g.Name, SomeNumber = g.SomeNumber })
                .Select(s => new { Id = s.Key.Id, Name = s.Key.Name, SomeNumber = s.Key.SomeNumber, Count = s.Count() })
                .GroupBy(g => g.Id).Select(s => new {Id = s.Key, Count = s.Count()}).ToListAsync();
```

Comment: Have you even tried yet? There's nothing particularly complicated about this SQL.

Comment: Yes I tried. I have a problem that I can't get the same result in count() with EF Core.
Oh, and the thing is I don't want to use Join() just Includes

Comment: Show your attempt and we will correct your query.

Comment: Sorry, I edited my post.

Comment: Does your data model have navigation properties?

Comment: Also, how does that sql even work? The columns selected are not the same as the columns grouped by

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this is corrected query. I have used Query syntax which is more readable when query has lot of joins or `SelectMany`.

```cs
var query = 
    from a in _dbContext.TableA
    from b in a.TableB
    from c in b.TableC
    where b.Status == "Approved" && c.Scope == "Scope1"
    group a by new { a.Id, a.Name, a.SomeNumber } into g
    select new 
    {
        g.Key.Id,
        g.Key.Name,
        g.Key.SomeNumber,
        Count = g.Count()
    }

var result = await query.ToListAsync();
```

Comment: You are the man ! It works perfect. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

It's maybe easier to start from the many end and work up through the navigation properties

```
tableC
  .Where(c => c.Scope == "Scope1" && c.BEntity.Status == "Approved")
  .GroupBy(c => new 
    {
      c.BEntity.AEntity.Id,
      c.BEntity.AEntity.Name,
      c.BEntity.AEntity.SomeNumber
    })
  .Select(g => new { g.Key.Id, g.Key.Name, g.Key.SomeNumber, Ct = g.Count()})
```

EF knows how to do joins when you navigate around the object tree in the where. By starting at the many and and working up to the 1 end of the relationship it means you don't have to get complex with asking "do any of the children of this parent have a status of ..."

Comment: It's interesting, I'll try this and let you know how it performing.

Comment: It works as well